# monacaで電源状態を取得する方法について

Tags: monaca

monacaを使用してbatterystatusを定期的に読み取るようなことは可能なのでしょうか？

サンプルにあるコード

```
window.addEventListener("batterystatus", onBatteryStatus, false);
function onBatteryStatus(info) {
    // Handle the online event
    console.log("Level: " + info.level + " isPlugged: " + info.isPlugged);
}
```

を実装してみたのですが、動作させることが出来ません。
すみませんが、アドバイスをお願い致します。

Comment: どのように「動作しない」のでしょうか、もうすこし具体的にお願いします。
あと、addEventListenerはdeviceready（または、ons.ready）内で実行していますか？

Comment: kumapanda様
addEventListenerはdevicereadyで実行することで改善されました。
返信ありがとうございました。